# How to implement a server using Netty to store large file uploads to HDFS?

Tags: file-upload, netty, blocking, hdfs

What I'm trying to do is to implement a web server using Netty to store large file uploads to HDFS as HDFS files.

My basic work flow is as follows:

1. an end user send an HTTP PUT/POST request (with payload say 1GB) to my Netty server
2. Server accepts the HTTP connection and parses method/uri/headers
3. Server makes a call in DFSClient to HDFS to create a file and obtain a handle (DFSClient.create is a blocking call)
4. Server receives the rest of the upstream in the HTTP request and writes to the HDFS handle chunk by chunk (writing each chunk to the HDFS handle is a blocking call)
5. server closes the HDFS handle and acknowledge back to client (closing HDFS handle is blocking call)

I'm having problems in making the above steps work. Because I don't know what is the best way to efficiently make blocking calls in Netty (blocking the whole event loop as little as possible).

Can anybody show me a correct way of implementing the above logic? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: As a follow up. Now I solved this problem by chaining multiple handlers in a pipeline. The main event loop will block if any blocking calls are made within. So to make blocking calls, one needs to create a separate thread pool using ordered executor and create another handler to put blocking calls. To expand this technique one step further, one can create multiple such thread pools forming multiple stages for a request handling. This is very similar to the SEDA (Staged-Event-Driven-Architecture). One thing worth special care is the back-pressure. Without it memory usage will be extremly high.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to block you will need to put an ExecutionHandler in front of the handler that will perform the blocking operation to not affect the other channels on the same IO-Thread.

Comment: What is the recommended way for ordering the chunks? How do you throttle if the client is writing too fast?

Comment: Thank you Norman. I have a further question regarding the usage of ExecutionHandler. What if I call sendUpstream() to pass down an event to my next handler? Will the event handler be called immediately, or it will get scheduled some time later by the event loop?